# Arquillian in Jakarta EE 10

Tags: java, testing, jakarta-ee, jboss-arquillian

i have search a lot about it but i couldnt find the right answer. So here is my question. Is there any instruction how to configure Arquillian with Jakarta EE 10?

I have tried to find some informations and i found some articles like this : https://medium.com/swlh/testing-jakarta-ee-9-components-with-arquillian-and-weld-f9e1add08895

But its about Jakarta EE 9.

If you give me any advices i will be so grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Does it mean when you upgrade your dependencies to Jakarta EE 10 it is not working?

Comment: Yes, i get  java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor and i can not find a way to resolve it.

Comment: I would suggest opening an issue in the project if you won't get an answer here  https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-core/issues/new

Comment: I've found this : https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-core/issues/444